# How many natural numbers between $2$ and $60$ have no primitive roots and require at least four squares to be expressed as a sum of squares?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, integers, square-numbers

> A natural number $n$ is called *individual* if $n$ has no primitive roots and at least $4$ squares are needed so that it is expressed as a sum of squares. How many natural numbers $n$ between $2$ and $60$ are there that are individual?

I have thought to use the following theorem:

Theorem. An integer $n \geq 2$ has a primitive root if and only if it is one of the following: $2, 4, p^a, 2p^a$, where $p$ is prime, $p\neq2$, and $a\geq1$.

But the natural number $n$ needs to be of the form $n=x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$.

How can we find how many $n$ there are that can be written as a constant multiplied by a power of a prime number?

Comment: @EricTowers Oh sorry, I meant between $2$ and $60$.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem) should help.

Comment: I do not think that both questions are linked. You answered the first one perfectly (when does a primitive root exist). The solution of the second : A positive integer is not the sum of $3$ perfect squares if and only if it is of the form $4^m\cdot (8n+7)$ with non-negative integers $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Only $4^1 \cdot (8n+7)$ can be between $2$ and $60$, right? And there are no primitive roots for $n=0,1$, right? So the desired natural numbers are: $4 \cdot 7$ and $4 \cdot (8+7)$. Am I right? @Peter

Comment: $(1)$ Sometimes, $1$ is considered to have a primitive root, but it is reasonable to omit it.For $n=0$ , I do not think that there is even something like a $n-th$ root. $(2)$ Do not forget the case $m=0$ (leading to $8n+7$).

Comment: At this case, we find two further natural numbers without primitive roots, for $n=1$ and $n=4$. So in general there are 4 such numbers, 15,28,39,60, right? @Peter

Comment: No, $n$ can be any non-negative integer not exceeding $6$ (if $m=0$). For $m=0$, the solutions are $7,15,23,31,39,47,55$. For $m=1$ , we have $28$ and $60$ (If $60$ is included). $m\ge 2$ leads to numbers already larger to $60$.

Comment: Sorry, you meant the part with the primitive roots ? For this question, first determine the primes upto $60$

Answer (score 1):

Things which force a natural number to not be individual:

- being $2$ or $4$,
- being a power of an odd prime,
- being twice a power of an odd prime,
- being a square,
- being representable as the sum of two squares, equivalently, by the [sum of two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem), not having any of its prime factors which are congruent to $3 \pmod{4}$ appear to an odd power, or
- being representable as the sum of three squares, equivalently, by [Legendre's three-square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem) theorem, not being of the form $4^a(8b+7)$ for nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$.

So the following are not individual in $[2, 60]$:

- $2$ and $4$;
- the powers of odd primes, $3, 9, 27$, $5, 25$, $7, 49$, $11$, $13$, $17$, $19$, $23$, $29$, $31$, $37$, $41$, $43$, $47$, $53$, and $59$;
- the twice powers of odd primes, $6, 18, 54$, $10, 50$, $14$, $22$, $26$, $34$, $38$, $46$, and $58$;
- the squares, $1$, $4$, $9$, $16$, $25$, $36$, and $49$; and
- not having an odd power of a $3 \pmod{4}$ prime, $8$, $20$, $32$, $40$, $45$, and $52$.

This only leaves $17$ canddiates.  For each, pulling out the largest power of $4$ and writing the resulting cofactor by the division algorithm with divisor $8$, this leaves (underlining those with remainder $7$ in the division):
\begin{align*}
12 &= 4^1 \cdot (0 \cdot 8 + 3)  \text{,}  \\
15 &= 4^0 \cdot (\underline{1 \cdot 8 + 7})  \text{,}  \\
21 &= 4^0 \cdot (2 \cdot 8 + 5)  \text{,}  \\
24 &= 4^1 \cdot (0 \cdot 8 + 6)  \text{,}  \\
28 &= 4^1 \cdot (\underline{0 \cdot 8 + 7})  \text{,}  \\
30 &= 4^0 \cdot (3 \cdot 8 + 6)  \text{,}  \\
33 &= 4^0 \cdot (4 \cdot 8 + 1)  \text{,}  \\
35 &= 4^0 \cdot (4 \cdot 8 + 3)  \text{,}  \\
39 &= 4^0 \cdot (\underline{4 \cdot 8 + 7})  \text{,}  \\
42 &= 4^0 \cdot (5 \cdot 8 + 2)  \text{,}  \\
44 &= 4^1 \cdot (1 \cdot 8 + 3)  \text{,}  \\
48 &= 4^1 \cdot (1 \cdot 8 + 4)  \text{,}  \\
51 &= 4^0 \cdot (6 \cdot 8 + 3)  \text{,}  \\
55 &= 4^0 \cdot (\underline{6 \cdot 8 + 7})  \text{,}  \\
56 &= 4^0 \cdot (7 \cdot 8 + 0)  \text{,}  \\
57 &= 4^0 \cdot (7 \cdot 8 + 1)  \text{, and}  \\
60 &= 4^1 \cdot (\underline{1 \cdot 8 + 7})  \text{.}  \\
\end{align*}
Therefore, the individual numbers in the given interval are $15$, $28$, $39$, $55$, and $60$.